# Adding a tag that is a synonym of a previously added tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, tag-synonyms

Here is what happens when one try to add a tag that is a synonym of a previously added tag:

[image]

How about adding some visual indicator that "grant" is marked as a synonym of "funding", and therefore cannot be added a tag, so that one doesn't think the tag doesn't exist?

Comment: I'm almost certain I saw a bug report about this recently, but I can't seem to dig it up. Maybe someone else can find it. (It may have been on M.SO.)